# Regex - Match any sequence of characters except a particular word in a URL

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a URL that contains any sequence of valid URL characters but not a particular word. The URL in question http://gateway.ovid.com and I want to match anything but the word 'gateway' so:

- http://abc123.ovid.com - would match
- http://abc.123.ovid.com - would match
- http://abc-123.ovid.com - would match
- http://fdfsffdfs.ovid.com - would match

but

- http://gateway.ovid.com - would **NOT** match

Something like the following:

```
^http://([a-z0-9\-\.]+|(?<!gateway))\.ovid\.com$
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

---

**Update:** Sorry forget to mention the language, it's C#.NET

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct except the extra '|' after '+'. Remove the '|'

```
^http://([a-z0-9\-\.]+(?<!gateway))\.ovid\.com$
```

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. I was trying every combination I could think of as well.

Comment: Some elaboration 8 years later would be nice ;-)